# Is mod required for ClojureScript array performance - or is it simply about bounds checking?

Tags: javascript, arrays, clojurescript, modulus

[Lau Jensen has this fantastic post](http://www.bestinclass.dk/blog/brians-brain-optimized-clojurescript-html5) on getting high performance from ClojureScript using arrays. One of the techniques he uses is an array get function that uses a mod function like so:

```
(defn mod [x m]
  (js* "((x%m)+m)%m"))

(defn get-cell
  [b x y]
  (js* "b[brianscript.core.mod(y,90)][brianscript.core.mod(x,90)]"))
```

Does the `mod` function do anything special in JavaScript - or is this simply Lau not doing a bounds check elsewhere and including it in his get function?

My question is: **Is `mod` required for ClojureScript array performance - or is it simply about bounds checking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brianscript.core.mod()` compiles down to exactly the same code as `cljs.core.mod()`. Here is the compiled clojurescript code:

```
cljs.core.mod = (function mod(n,d){return (((n % d) + d) % d);
```

His reimplementation of `get-cell` was also unnecessary: his original version using `aset` will compile to the same javascript code.

He cannot use the js `%` operator (actually pronounced "remainder", not "modulus") because he wants coordinate lookups in his neighbor-checking functions to "wrap around" the board. E.g. If he is at coordinate 0, and wants to check the cell to his left, the index is 89, not -1. `-1 % 90 = -1`, but `mod(-1, 90) = 89`.

If he is seeing any performance benefit from writing his own mod, it is *not* because he is getting more "down to the metal" than cljs.mod. Possibly the javascript vm was deoptimizing cljs.core.mod because it was being called with arguments of inconsistent types across the life of the program. By "cloning" the mod function and always calling it with small int arguments, the VM might have been able to optimize it better and more consistently. This is just speculation, though.

There is a lot in his article that is simply wrong. He appears in many cases to be applying java/clojure reasoning to javascript/clojurescript incorrectly (he is porting this application from Clojure after all).  For example, his section on using multi-dimensional arrays is citing *Java* bytecode to argue that *javascript* multidimensional arrays will be faster, which is completely not true. (There are no multidim arrays in JS--perhaps some JS VM will optimize that case, but the only way to know is to measure.) In another place he says:

> The real value here [of using numbers instead of keywords], is that it allows us to use an int-array, which performs roughly 10-12% faster than a non-typed array.

In clojurescript, `int-array` (and all the `*-array` and `make-array` functions) are aliases for a normal javascript array. In Clojure these produce Java primitive arrays of different types, but in Clojurescript they are all simply `new Array()`. He gets a boost in performance because he is removing the overhead of comparing keyword objects instead of numbers, and possibly because his vm is under-the-hood using a more compact array representation because it notices its full of small integers instead of pointers.

Optimizing javascript performance is extremely difficult. You must benchmark *every* change, in multiple browsers, using realistic inputs and call patterns. Different VMs will optimize different approaches differently and there are very few rules of thumb that always work. A good thing to read about optimizing js is [Javascript performance for madmen](https://github.com/sq/JSIL/wiki/JavaScript-Performance-For-Madmen), which really just gives you a taste of how unpredictable JS performance can be. You should also read [David Nolen's post on optimizing clojurescript](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/06/10/porting-notchs-minecraft-demo-to-clojurescript/) which Jensen cites (David Nolen is a lead Clojurescript developer and maintainer).